# Horizontal hovering navigation menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, hover, css-position

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS. I have created a horizontal menu and the drop-downs hover as they should.

However, I want the drop down to appear ONLY when the mouse hovers over the links, and not the space below it which occupies the actual drop-down content.

If someone can please point out why this is happening and how I could fix it that would be great.

Here is the HTML and CSS.

```css
nav{

    text-align:center;
    font-family:myFirstFont;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:320px;
    top:56px;
}

.navigation {
    list-style-type:none;
    word-spacing:50px;
    max-width:100%;
    font-size:1.2em;
    position:relative;

}

.navigation li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.navigation a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#00a8e7;
}

 
.navigation ul {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:justify;

}

.navigation ul li {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    right:40px;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.navigation li:hover ul li{
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
                </ul>
                
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">WEBSITE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">LOGO</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">WEBSITES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LOGO DESIGN</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">PHONE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EMAIL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
nav{

    text-align:center;
    font-family:myFirstFont;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:320px;
    top:56px;
}

.navigation {
    list-style-type:none;
    word-spacing:50px;
    max-width:100%;
    font-size:1.2em;
    position:relative;

}

.navigation li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.navigation a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#00a8e7;
}

 
.navigation ul {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:justify;

}

ul.inner li {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    right:40px;
    
    
}

.navigation li:hover ul.inner li{
    display:block
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
                </ul>
                
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                  <ul class="inner">
                      <li><a href="#">WEBSITE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">LOGO</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li><a href="#">WEBSITES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LOGO DESIGN</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li><a href="#">PHONE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EMAIL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you Sagar. The solution worked. I understand what you have done. Can you just explain to me why ul.inner li works and .navigation ul li doesn't? I am essentially doing the same thing just calling the broader class i.e .navigation and then ul li, instead of creating a class for the inner ul and caling it by ul.inner li. THANKS

Comment: because you have two ul in .navigation so if you only use .navigation ul in css the css will apply on both that's why i used class for inner ul.. WELCOME

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the main li elements (About, Services, Portfolio...) the class="top". Then edit the CSS file to .top.li:hover ul li {...}.

Comment: I tired that it did not work... I have tried a bunch of different methods as well but nothing seems to work. I also gave the .navigation ul a border and that shows the problem.... but if i change the position of that then my dropdown wont be immediately under the main li .